# TinyMCE Plugin internationalization

Tags: internationalization, tinymce

I have create a plugin for tinyMCE and It does not load the language file.

The plugin folder stracture is that:

```
/content_columns/
/content_columns/content_columns
/content_columns/langs/
/content_columns/langs/el.js
```

My plugin code is that:

```
(
    function()
    {
        tinyMCE.PluginManager.requireLangPack('content_columns');

        tinyMCE.create(
            'tinymce.plugins.ContentColumns',
            {
                init: function(ed, url)
                {
                    ed.onNodeChange.add(
                        function(ed, cm, n)
                        {
                            cm.setActive('content_columns', n.nodeName = 'IMG');
                        }
                    );
                },
                createControl: function(n, cm)
                {
                    switch(n)
                    {
                        case 'content_columns':
                            var mlb = cm.createListBox(
                                'content_columns',
                                {
                                    title : 'content_columns.title',
                                    onselect : function(v)
                                    {}
                                }
                            );

                            mlb.add('One half', 'one_half');
                            return mlb;
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            }
        );

        tinymce.PluginManager.add('content_columns', tinymce.plugins.ContentColumns);
    }
)();
```

and my el.js file is that:

```
tinyMCE.addI18n(
    'el.content_columns',
{
        title: "Test Title"
}
);
```

While the plugin is working good, I can't load the language file. Any idea why I can't load it ?

Comment: I assume you are setting the "language" config item to "el" when you load TinyMCE?

Comment: Yes this is "el". Also I have observed that the el.js is not loading at all. Additionally, after a debug I did with Chrome console I discovered that the TinyMCE language name is set to el. I have to tell you that I use the TinyMCE over the WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did seems to be fine. I think it might be a problem that  you are using a `"_"` in your pluginname. What happens if you remove that character from the name (and the corresponding lines in your langauge file and plugin?)